# Detect if you are adding or updating within an EditorTemplate View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik-mvc, mvc-editor-templates

I have a View that I am using as an EditorTemplate.  I want to limit what the user can edit vs. what they can insert.  My EditorTemplate View is typed as SomeModel and I know that if SomeModel.Id is not 0, that means we are doing an edit, otherwise we are doing an insert.  I thought I'd be able to do something like:

```
@if (Model.Id == 0) 
{ 
  //show "insert-specific" UI 
}
```

but for some reason, I always get 0's, nulls, default, etc. when I check via `Model.` whereas the Html helper methods pick up the true value just fine, such as:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id)
```

Again, the value of `Model.Id` is always 0, even when `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id)` shows another value.

Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Note:  Not sure that it matters, but I'm using the Telerik MVC Grid control.  It doesn't seem to allow for a different View for inserting vs. editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo,

If you are using Ajax binding then the EditorTemplate is serialized and send to the client where it is re-populated with different values each time you edit a record or add new record. 
If you are using ajax binding  then you can use the OnEdit client event and check whether or not the **e.mode** is **edit** or **insert**. Then you can manipulate that editor with JavaScript.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little more, as it might be a solution to my problem.  What would the OnEdit event look like?  Are you able to specify a new View (by name)?

Comment: No, there is no such thing as View when using ajax binding - everything is JavaScript - here is a link to the documentation

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#OnEdit